# Android Studio how to test multithread?

Tags: android, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

At the unit test, sometimes I want to test some Thread,just like POST/GET request.But if the Thread runtime is delay,the unit test is stop,and i can't get the result.just like:

```
    @Test
    public void testThread() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assertTrue(false);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

When I test the code,I always can't receive the AssertionError.

I am a novice,I don't know the most of JUnit library,and I think the android JUnit sometimes is differ Java.

Is there way to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with JUnit since I'm not acquainted to it, but maybe your best (and easier) choice is using "Log".

First import:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

Then use the following snippet of  code:

```
Log.e("XXX", "Thread is working!");
```

When the thread finishes, you'll get a notification on the logcat with the key "XXX".

Comment: @SergeBarjola How do you verify Logging output with JUnit?